# Simples Implementação em algoritmo de Dijkstra

Tags: c, algoritmo

Tenho um grafo orientado e um código que usa o algoritmo de Dijkstra, que retorna os caminhos de menor custo.

Porém ele está retornando todos do caminhos de menor custo, e eu preciso somente do caminho de menor custo dos vértices 0 a 3:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define QTD 9999
#define MAX 5

void dijkstra(int G[MAX][MAX],int n,int inicial);

int main()
{
    int i,j,u,l,p;
    int G[MAX][MAX];
    
    for(l=0 ;l < MAX; l++)
    {
        for( p=0; p< MAX; p++)
        {
            G[l][p] = -1;
        }
    }
    
    G[0][1]=100;
    G[0][2]=800;
    G[1][3]=500;
    G[1][4]=700;
    G[2][1]=200;
    G[2][3]=500;
    G[4][3]=100;
    
    for(l=0 ;l < MAX; l++)
    {
        for( p=0; p< MAX; p++)
        {
            printf("%d,",G[l][p]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\nInforme o node inicial:");
    scanf("%d",&u);
    dijkstra(G,MAX,u);

    return 0;
}

void dijkstra(int G[MAX][MAX],int n,int inicial)
{

    int custo[n][n],distancia[n],pred[n];
    int visitado[n],cont,distanciamin,proxno,i,j;


    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            if(G[i][j]==-1)
                custo[i][j]=QTD;
            else
                custo[i][j]=G[i][j];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        distancia[i]=custo[inicial][i];
        pred[i]=inicial;
        visitado[i]=0;
    }

    distancia[inicial]=0;
    visitado[inicial]=1;
    cont=1;

    while(cont<n-1)
    {
        distanciamin=QTD;

        
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            if(distancia[i]<distanciamin&&!visitado[i])
            {
                distanciamin=distancia[i];
                proxno=i;
            }

        //verifica se existe melhor caminho atraves do proximo node
        visitado[proxno]=1;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(!visitado[i])
                if(distanciamin+custo[proxno][i]<distancia[i])
                {
                    distancia[i]=distanciamin+custo[proxno][i];
                    pred[i]=proxno;
                }
        }
        cont++;
    }

    //imprime o caminho e a distancia de cada node
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(i!=inicial)
        {
            printf("\nDistancia do no%d=%d",i,distancia[i]);
            printf("\nCaminho=%d",i);

            j=i;
            do
            {
                j=pred[j];
                printf("<-%d",j);
            }while(j!=inicial);
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/393902/d%c3%bavida-sobre-parte-do-c%c3%b3digo-do-algoritmo-de-dijkstra?rq=1) tem conteúdo que o possa ajudar

Answer (score 0):

O algoritmo de Dijkstra tem dois aspectos importantes:

- Algoritmo Guloso, desta forma você precisa pegar o vértice mais apetitoso (com o menor caminho).
- Busca em Profundidade, isso parece ser o problema do seu código.

Siga a abstração da seguinte lógica:

- Compare os vértices adjacentes do vértice inicial.
- Escolha a Aresta com menor peso.
- Siga a aresta para mudar o vértice, uma vez no vértice repita o processo anterior.

O grafo abaixo é exatamente igual ao do seu programa, um detalhe geralmente as implementações do algoritmo de Dijkstra requerem além de um vértice inicial um vértice de destino, assim você consegue otimizar o código e não precisa ficar fazendo uma busca cega. Evitando assim um loop infinito.

Para fazer o algoritmo de Dijkstra funcionar sem usar o um vértice de destino, você vai precisar **implementar os recursos do algoritmo A***  pois ele utiliza tabelas auxiliares para saber por quais vértices ele já passou, e qual caminho teve o menor custo.

[image: Grafo]